# Mysql Index for concat select

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, index-tuning, explain

For Below Query

```
SELECT MAX(CONCAT(date, ' ', last_entry)) AS LAST_LOG
    FROM entry_log
    WHERE TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM card_no)='2948'
```

I've index on

```
date
card_no
date,last_entry
date,last_entry,card_no
```

My Explain Shows

```
id  select_type     table       type    possible_keys   key             key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE          entry_log   index   NULL            date_last_card  158         NULL    103766  Using where; Using index
```

My Explain Extended shows

```
id  select_type     table           type    possible_keys   key             key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra   
1     SIMPLE        entry_log       index   NULL            date_last_card  158         NULL    103766  100.00      Using where; Using index
```

I want to know which index can i remove/use, Am i in right path, How should i improve execution time for above query?

```
CREATE TABLE `entry_log` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `card_no` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `first_entry` time NOT NULL,
 `last_entry` time NOT NULL,
 `all_entry` text NOT NULL,
 `entry_time` datetime NOT NULL,
 `update_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9308 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: What type is the `last_entry` and `card_no`? Varchar?

Comment: last_entry is time and card_no is varchar(50)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `card_no` and `log_entry` have `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` type, I would first add an index on `(card_no, date, last_entry)`:

```
ALTER TABLE entry_log
  ADD INDEX card_no__date__last_entry__ix
    (card_no, date, last_entry) ;
```

and then use this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(date, ' ', last_entry) AS LAST_LOG 
FROM entry_log 
WHERE card_no = LPAD('2948', 32, '0')
ORDER BY date DESC, last_entry DESC
LIMIT 1 ;
```

<strike>The values in the `IN` list should include all lengths up to the maximum allowed by the type. The example above is for `VARCHAR(8)`.</strike>

Update: since it was clarified that the `card_no` column is always 32 characters and left padded with zeroes, the query condition is simplified from:
<sub><strike>`WHERE card_no IN ('2948', '02948', '002948', ..., '000...0002948')`</strike> to

`WHERE card_no = RIGHT(CONCAT('000..00', '2948'), 32)` or simply to

`WHERE card_no = LPAD('2948', 32, '0')`</sub>

Comment: I always need to check max last entry for one card

Comment: So, what do the values look like? Is it `'000....002948'` - always 50 characters stored? Or could it be less?

Comment: Yes always 32 characters like '000....001234' and '00000...000003'

Comment: using Ricks advice if `i use SELECT MAX(CONCAT(date, ' ', last_entry)) AS LAST_LOG
FROM entry_log
WHERE card_no = RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000000000000000000000000000', '2475'), 32)` Then it seems using card index... should i go with that?

Comment: Did you try my answer (adding the index and using my query)?

Comment: I do have a index `date,last_entry,card_no` should i re-arrange it like `card_no, date, last_entry` ? and what should be IN statement like `RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000000000000000000000000000', '2475'), 32)` ?

Comment: I suggest you add an index. Keep that, too, as it may be used by other queries. If you are happy with the results, you can then drop the index on `(card_no)` as this new one will be enough to cover queries against only `card_no` as well.

Comment: As for the query, I have edited the answer 10 minutes ago. Use the new query (with LPAD).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23313/discussion-between-farness-and-evilcube).

Answer (score 3):

Cleanse your data before storing it.  Otherwise, INDEXes may be useless.

I this particular case, the TRIM function is hiding card_no, making the INDEX on card_no useless.

*This* SELECT would run a lot faster because of the index:

```
SELECT MAX(CONCAT(date, ' ', last_entry)) AS LAST_LOG
    FROM entry_log
    WHERE card_no = '2948'
```

OK, you don't like the Cleanse advice.  And your `card_no` is always an 8-digit number.  In that case, this would allow the use of the index:

```
WHERE card_no = RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000', '2948'), 8)
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we won't have to guess any more.

**Edit**

If a `card_no` is just a number, but with some extra zeros in front, it could be stored more compactly as an `INT`, `BIGINT`, or `DECIMAL(...)`.  Then do the `LPAD` to prefix it with the needed zeros when fetching it.

`SMALLINT` (2 bytes) can handle 4 digits, as with your example.
`INT` (4 bytes) can handle 9 digits.
`BIGINT` (8 bytes) can handle 18 digits.
`DECIMAL(32,0)` (15 bytes) can handle 32 digits.  A smaller number could be used if you never need a full 32.

You would need to pick whatever size will handle the largest `card_no` you can have.

`VARCHAR(50)` takes 2 + N bytes, where N is the number of digits.  If `card_no` varies a lot is length, this might still be the best bet.

**Edit2**

If you have a lot of rows for a card_no, it will run a lot faster if you do these:

- Combine `date` (date) and `last_entry` (time) into a single column of `DATETIME` datatype.  I'll call the column `last_log`.
- `SELECT MAX(last_log) AS LAST_LOG`
- `INDEX(card, last_log)`

Rationale:  The INDEX can do essentially all the work of the MAX -- this will run a lot faster.

(Note:  This comment about `last_log` is independent of the discussion on leading zeros for card_no.  Be sure to formulate the `WHERE` clause as `WHERE card_no = ...` in order to make use of the index.)

**Edit 3**

In the newest versions of MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10, you can index "virtual" columns.

Comment: I suppose you wanted to write `RIGHT(..., 8)` in the last line.

Comment: Oops -- yes....

Comment: actually card_no is a 32 byte character and it could be 1 to 10000 so what should be RIGHT(CONCAT('?', '*'),?) value?

Comment: Please see the update